# Spring: inject properties file into map

Tags: java, spring

I've got a property file below:

```
transition.s1=s2,s5
transition.s2=s4,s1
...................
```

*Question:* How to inject those properties into `Map<String, String>`? Can you provide an example?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fill map, configured with spring, from properties file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416156/how-to-fill-map-configured-with-spring-from-properties-file)

Comment: @BorisTreukhov I don't find that answer full. Please can you provide a tested example

Comment: What don't you understand with the answer in the `<util:properties>` example?

Comment: @WillKeeling Mala onda

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In case of XML configuration

```
public class StateGraph {
    public StateGraph(Map<String, String> a){ 
    ...
    }
    boolean getStateTransition(){
    ...
    }
}
```

as properties implements map you can supply it as constructor

```
<bean class="com.xxx.xxx.StateGraph">
    <constructor-arg>
        <util:properties location="classpath:props.properties"/> 
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

please note that Spring will do all [the required generic type conversions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements-strongly-typed)

> If you are using Java 5 or Java 6, you will be aware that it is
>   possible to have strongly typed collections (using generic types).
>   That is, it is possible to declare a Collection type such that it can
>   only contain String elements (for example). If you are using Spring to
>   dependency inject a strongly-typed Collection into a bean, you can
>   take advantage of Spring's type-conversion support such that the
>   elements of your strongly-typed Collection instances will be converted
>   to the appropriate type prior to being added to the Collection.

If you are using the programmatic configuration instead then you will have to do it in the `@Configuration` class yourself - see [Converting java.util.Properties To HashMap<string,string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209260/converting-java-util-properties-to-hashmapstring-string).