# Use properties file in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am a newbie to Spring framework. In my Spring application there are some details as below those details needs to be maintain in a properties file.

```
Transaction Name     Transaction Id
TXT_CCO              = 70001
TXT_CCI              = 70002
TXT_SSM              = 20005
```

In my controller, there is an action as below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/ValidateWalletAmount**"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String validateWalletAmount(@RequestParam("mobile") String mobile,
                                           @RequestParam("pin") String merchant_pin,
                                           @RequestParam("provider") String provider,
                                           @RequestParam("currency_type") String currency_type,
                                           @RequestParam("amount") String amount) {
    //TO DO - Get txnTypeId by provider

    return "02 | 1000.00 | 0.00";
}
```

According to the request parameter **provider** I need to get the relevant transaction type id. As an example, if the provider is **TXT_CCO** transaction type id should be **70001**.

Can someone please help me to achieve this

Comment: What did you try? what issue are you facing? *as is* this is too broad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have 2 options

1. Load the properties using `<util:properties />`
2. Use `@PropertySource` and the `Environment` abstraction.

### Using `<util:properties />`

To simply load a properties file you can use the `PropertiesFactoryBean` or easier the `<util:properties />` tag (which uses the `PropertiesFactoryBean` underneath but is just easier to configure). See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util-properties) for more information.

Simply add the following to your xml configuration

```
<util:properties id="transactions" location="classpath:transaction.properties" />
```

Now you have a `Properties` bean named `transactions` which you can inject into your controller after which you can use that to obtain the property you need.

```
@Autowired
private Properties transactions;
```

### Using `@PropertySource` and `Environment` abstraction

Another solution is to add a `@Configuration` class with a `@PropertySource` to load the properties. After that you can use the `Environment` to obtain the properties. See the [`Environment`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-environment) section in the reference guide for more information.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:transaction.properties")
public class MyConfiguration {}
```

In your controller you can use the `Environment` to obtain the properties.

```
@Autowired
private Environment env;
```

**Resource Support**

Of course the Spring property support is usable with the [Resource loading](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) approach of Spring. So `file:` and `http:` prefixes work as well, as well as the default loading rules applying to the used `ApplicationContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your properties file name is "messages.properties", in that case you need to have something similar to following in your applicationContext.xml file.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

Make sure that your properties file is in the class path.

In your controller class, auto-wire the messagesource object

```
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;
```

To compare the transaction type id you can have code similar to below:

```
   if(provider.trim().equals("TXT_CCO")){
        String transactionTypeId=messageSource.getMessage("TXT_CCO", null, Locale.ENGLISH).trim();
    }
```

Comment: @Ann Basically you need to inject the property file values as a Map object in your controller class. You can also have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21280982/1898397

Comment: That isn't the right way, that is for message resolving and I18N support. For simply loading a properties file use `<util:properties />` and simply inject the resulting `Properties` object in your controller.