# Reading properties file under WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring

I have a webapplication on Java spring. I need to read application specific settings when the application will be initialized. I have added `app.properties` under `WebContent/WEB-INF` but I am not able to get that file from the class. 
If I provide 
    `InputStream  input = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("WEB-INF/spring.properties");
    prop.load(input);`

then it is showing file is not present. I can not use absolute path. What will be the path?

Comment: Why aren't you letting Spring load the properties? Why are you messing around with that yourself?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32195550/use-properties-file-in-spring/32196546#32196546 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Javadoc `ServletContext.getResource`:

> The path must begin with a / and is interpreted as relative to the
>   current context root, or relative to the /META-INF/resources directory
>   of a JAR file inside the web application's /WEB-INF/lib directory.

Therefore try

```
InputStream in = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/<filename>");
```