# How to store properties into a Map

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a properties file like for example *.properties
key1 = value1
key2 = value2

Is there way to store all the key value pairs in a hash map?

Comment: So you want all properties in a specific property file or from all property files?

Comment: from a specific property file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring: inject properties file into map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21278951/spring-inject-properties-file-into-map)

Answer (score 1):

If the question relates to the Spring framework, then you can create Configuration Beans based on a *.properties or *.yml files.

Example MyAppProperties.java

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "props")
public class MyAppProperties {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

And your properties that start with ***props.map.**** will be available through this Configuration Bean, which can be obtained from the application context.

```
props.map.key1=value1
props.map.key2=value2
```

For more information, see the documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.java-bean-binding