# Inject map of beans using Spring from properties file

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to control which beans populate a map from a properties file using Spring 3.  I believe this question is similar to [How to fill map, configured with spring, from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15416156/2083907), except in my case, my properties file has names of beans:

```
key1=bean1
key2=bean2
```

I tried an xml like:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="habeas corpus"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bean2" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="platanos verdes"/>
</bean>

<bean id="map" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <constructor-arg ref="props"/>
</bean>

<util:properties id="props" location="classpath:test.properties" />
```

But then `map` is `{key1: "bean1", key2: "bean2"}`, whereas I want `{key1: "habeas corpus", key2: "platanos verdes"}`.

I am not wed to this approach, so any other ideas how I can control which beans populate the map would be great.