# How can I tell Spring to use a Java map to resolve property placeholder?

Tags: java, spring

I have a `Map<String, String>` and I would like to tell Spring to use this when creating beans and resolving property placeholders. What is the easiest way to do this? Here is an example:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
   private String myValue;

    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Value("${key.in.map}") String myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }

    public String getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
    propertyMap.put("key.in.map", "value.in.map");
    ApplicationContext ctx = ...;
    // Do something???
    ctx.getBean(MyClass.class).getMyValue(); // Should return "value.in.map"
}
```

Comment: Whether it is possible to inject the Map key into spring bean property that is secondary. First of all you are doing `new HashMap<>();`. Spring context won't be able to recognize this bean. You will have to obtain this bean as well from Spring Context by doing something like `ctx.getBean(java.util.HashMap.class)`. Then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285202/inject-map-of-beans-using-spring-from-properties-file) is example where user was able to access property using ` <entry key="#{props['key1']}"`. Here props is of type java.util.Properties-which is subclass of HashTable

Comment: @Amit.rk3 Thanks for the input Amrit. I'm not sure you fully understand the setting. I'm not interested in doing `ctx.getBean(HashMap.class)`. I have a mapping of String to String and I would like to tell Spring to use this map for resolving property placeholders.

Comment: OK. In your question you mentioned java map. That got me confused :) . Anyways so for just mapping strings from properties list, you can keep the entries in .properties file and load it. There are lots of answers for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring provides a [`MapPropertySource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/MapPropertySource.html) which you can register with your `ApplicationContext`'s `Environment` (you'll need a `ConfigurableEnvironment` which most `ApplicationContext` implementations provide).

These registered `PropertySource` values are used by the resolvers (in order) to find a value for your placeholder names.

Here's a complete example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Example {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        // can also add it here
        //configurer.setPropertySources(propertySources);
        return configurer;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Object> propertyMap = new HashMap<>();
        propertyMap.put("key.in.map", "value.in.map");
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        MapPropertySource propertySource = new MapPropertySource("map-source", propertyMap);
        ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
        ctx.register(Example.class);
        ctx.refresh();

        MyClass instance = ctx.getBean(MyClass.class);
        System.out.println(instance.getMyValue());
    }
}

@Component
class MyClass {
    private String myValue;
    @Autowired
    public MyClass(@Value("${key.in.map}") String myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
    public String getMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is the behavior any different than using the properties file directly? For instance, what happens if you try to do `@Value("my.int.key") int myValue`?

Comment: @Max When you register a properties file, behind the scenes, Spring registers a `PropertiesPropertySource`. These are registered in some order. The `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` iterates through the sources, attempting to find a given property, ex. `my.int.key`. If it does, it uses it. If it doesn't it moves on until there are no more sources left. At this point it will throw an exception.

Comment: But the property file is a mapping of string -> string since there is no type information available in the file. The type of the MapPropertySource is map of string -> object. The example for the `int` was to ask if I need to take care of converting `int` types?

Comment: @Max Oh. No, Spring is being more general. It has a number of default converters that can convert from a `String` value (from a properties file) to a pre-defined types, `int` included.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up using. I convert the Map to a properties file.

```
Map<String, String> propertyMap = ...;
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.putAll(propertyMap);

AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
ConfigurableBeanFactory beanFactory = ctx.getBeanFactory();
PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setProperties(properties);
beanFactory.registerSingleton(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.class.getSimpleName(),
                    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve the similar functionality although may not what you're looking.

Here's my code:

> application.properties

```
key.in.map=value.in.map
```

> beans.xml

http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.chatar" />
</beans:beans>
```

> Config.java

```
package com.chatar.batch;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean(name = "mapper")
    public PropertiesFactoryBean mapper() {
        PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("META-INF/spring/application.properties"));
        return bean;
    }
}
```

> MyClazz.java

```
package com.chatar.batch;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class MyClazz {
    @Value("#{mapper}")
    private Map<String, String> props;

    public Map<String, String> getProps() {
        return props;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        System.out.println("Value:: " + context.getBean(MyClazz.class).getProps().get("key.in.map")); // Should return
    }
}
```

> Output: Value:: value.in.map

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed answer. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but it gave me some good ideas.